# Adding UDEV rules makes Raspberry boot too slow

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, udev

I have an issue when I add this rule in my /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:

`ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{serial}="XXXXXXX",RUN+=/usr/local/bin/startApache.sh"`

The rule works correctly (the sh file start service Apache2) but when I reboot the system the boot becomes very very slow and it stops for some minute on the following command:

*Starting Remount Root and Kernel File System...*

After some minutes, the system boots correctly. If at the boot the USB drive is not inserted, the boot is fast as usual.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!